# ido-read-directory-name does not show matches in minibuffer

Tags: completion, ido

I'm trying to read a directory path using `ido-read-directory-name`to prompt in the minibuffer. I have `(ido-everywhere t)`and `(ido-enable-flex-matching t)` enabled, and I'm running emacs 24.5.1.

I expect `ido-read-directory-name`to behave like `ido-read-file-name`, by showing all possible flex matches in the minibuffer. I expect it to show me ONLY directory name matches (not file name matches), since I'm reading for directory names.

But instead of showing matches in the minibuffer, it shows only `[.]`after the current directory match, like so `/usr/bin/[.]`, which is not what I want.

If I hit TAB once, potential directory matches are displayed in a regular emacs buffer (named "*Ido Completions*"), as emacs normally does for Apropos, Help, describe-function matches, etc. The buffer says "Potential matches: " and displays a lonely single dot.

If I hit TAB a second time, the single dot is replaced with a full list of potential directory matches, and is displayed in the "*Ido Completions*" buffer as Emacs normally does. Seeing that, I can start typing a desired match, and the minibuffer will eventually match it.

Sometimes if I type a single letter in the minibuffer, and then backspace to erase it, the usual (nice) flex match display shows up, with something like this `../blah/blah/dir/{. | match1/ | match2/ | ...}`showing. From this, I'm thinking that `ido-read-directory-name`knows how to properly show directory matches in the minibuffer, but for some reason is not doing it by default.

Why doesn't `ido-read-directory-name`display the possible directory matches in the minibuffer? Is there some variable that I might have set wrong? (I looked at the 50? possible ido-* variables with describe-variable, but couldn't see anything. Ditto for searching the SO forums, and the net.

I love `ido-read-file-name`, but ido-read-directory seems to exhibit very different behavior for me. Ideas to try, anyone? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. For clarification, all you want `ido` is to present you with possible sub-directory names?
2. From my interpretation, what you want is ido-dired with `C-x d`.

This allows you to use dired mode in tandem with ido mode. Here's what that looks like for me when executed in a blank buffer:

[image]

After that command, I can navigate around my directories (only, no file names) and choose the directory.

3. Here's a post on overflow where someone has a problem similar to yours.

The solution offered is one I personally use, which is `ido-ubiquitous`, a package that attempts to implement `ido` functionality basically in any buffer possible 'without breaking anything.' It's on [Github](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/ido-ubiquitous) and [MELPA](https://stable.melpa.org/#/ido-ubiquitous). It is a really powerful package that can do a lot more than what I use it for, so I personally highly recommend it.

Together with normal `ido`, I am able to have near universal buffer completion with just the following three commands:

```
(ido-mode 1) 
(ido-everywhere 1)
(ido-ubiquitous-mode 1)
```

Installing [Smex](https://github.com/nonsequitur/smex) also enhances navigating any `M-` related commands, and only requires `(smex-initialize)` and rebinding `M-x` and `M-X`.

With a lot of emacs minor and major modes, there are various configurations with minor differences so if you don't choose the right one from the start, it can cause confusion/look like it doesn't work. Additionally, if you try to combine modes that *theoretically* should work together, it goes without saying that they still might not for obscure reasons down in the code itself. At minimum, I hope this answer put you in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Zaile, thank you for taking the time to post a screenshot and suggestions for ubiquitous mode, etc. I've been trying out normal ido before I explore the jumps to icicles, ido ubiquitous, etc. Your screenshot is exactly what I want to see (and expect to see) in the minibuffer. But even using ido-dired, it behaves as I described above. One tab/space shows me a dot in a normal buffer, a second space/tab shows a full list, typing a char and backspacing shows the nice minibuffer list. And I don't want dired, since I'm calling `(ido-read-directory-name ...)` from code.. Weird behavior.

Comment: (two part comment, part 1)

I cannot personally speak for the niche functions of `ido-mode` because from the get go, I set up my installation with `ido-ubiquitous`. Similarly, I have never used `icicles` because ubiquitous has worked really well for me.

I understand if you want to work you way up, but, that said, I am ~nearly~ promising you instant results with the set up I use with the catch that there is not something else conflicting in your init file. Opinion aside,
`ido-mode`, according to the GNU manual, was  meant for "switch[ing] between buffers and visit files and directories..."

Comment: (part two) and what you seem to want is a very specific behavior out of `ido`. You may very well be able to get it to behave as you want without any additional packages, but searching directories alone was a function `dired-mode` was kind of build with in mind. That's why `C-x d` command works as well as it does: that's the behavior it was designed to have. Ultimately, while I can't help you further along what you want to do (and I respect your approach/desired execution), may I suggest you try a temp init file with the configuration I suggested? That way you at least get to try it & see.

Comment: Also, I'm glad to have given what advice I had to offer, no problem. I like to help as much as I can. I am pretty new to emacs and I understand how difficult it can be to figure out. That's a characteristic that seems to apply regardless to how experienced some users are and (as I've sort of mentioned), I think it ultimately comes down to the fact emacs has so many modes with so many sub-functions that are easy to forget, conflict, or just misuse.